# How do I get the column count of a table when there are cells with rowspan/colspan?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

How do I get the column count of a table when there are cells with rowspan/colspan?

**UPDATE:** In this question I mean the classical (as far as I know) use of tables, when it's necessary to use the `colspan`, though it's not required by the specification (and table will look ugly but it will be valid).

I need JavaScript/jQuery to get `11` for the following table (as 11 is the maximum number of columns for this table):

```
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="3">Lorem</th>
            <th rowspan="3">ipsum</th>
            <th rowspan="3">dolor</th>
            <th colspan="4">sit</th>
            <th colspan="4">amet</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3">consectetur</th>
            <th rowspan="2">adipisicing</th>
            <th rowspan="2">elit</th>
            <th rowspan="2">sed</th>
            <th rowspan="2">do</th>
            <th rowspan="2">eiusmod</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>tempor</th>
            <th>incididunt</th>
            <th>ut</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/toahb3a3/

My personal solution is:

```
$(function(){
  var max = 0;
  $('tr').each(function(){
    var current = 0;
    $(this).find('th').each(function(){
      var colspan = $(this).attr('colspan');
      current += Number(colspan ? colspan : 1);
    });
    max = Math.max(current, max);
  });
  console.log(max);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mt7qhbqd/

**UPDATE:** To solve this problem we need the sum of `th` elements plus their `colspan` in the very first row of `thead`. Thanks to Andy for his code, it's really compact and it gave me the thought that I need only the first row. Also, thanks to Quentin who pointed me to the case when `colspan` is not necessarily used, so Andy's alogrithm won't work (but Quentin's will). Also thanks to Quentin for helping me with the title, as my English isn't good enough.

Comment: there is no `11` in any td node.

Comment: Don't be so fast, read the question. I need to get the columns count, and it's 11.

Comment: What you want to do is to count the maximum number of columns in the table, right?

Comment: @rubentd Yes. Yes. Excuse me, stackoverflow is very smart and I have to add this text here. E.g. I cannot say just "@rubentd Yes."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reduce` over the colspan info.

```
var th = document.querySelectorAll('table thead tr:first-child th');

var cols = [].reduce.call(th, function (p, c) {
  var colspan = c.getAttribute('colspan') || 1;
  return p + +colspan;
}, 0);
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/toahb3a3/3/)

Comment: Thanks, your code is much more compact and it's not depend on jQuery.

Comment: This assumes that the first row will have a cell for every column. That isn't a requirement of HTML tables.

Comment: Andy's code doesn't assumes that. It assumes that the first row have to have either columns or/and number of spanned columns. Sum that and you'll get the maximum amount of columns in whole table.

Comment: @Martin — No. I didn't say a *unique* cell for each column. The maximum columns for the table is determined by the row with the most columns, not the first row.

Comment: @Quentin - in Andy's code the count of columns is reached by counting both cells **and** colspan. Could you please provide a working example, when Andy's code won't work?

Comment: @Martin — `<table><tr><th>1<th>2<tr><td>1<td>2<td>3</table>`

Comment: @Quentin OK I see what you mean, please see the UPDATE at the top of my question (and "thanks" at the bottom).

Answer (score 2):

To calculate the number of columns in a table, you need to find the row with the most columns in it. To do that, you need to test each row in turn, but take into account any cells from previous rows that span into it.

This should do the trick.

```
// Store the cells in each row
var rows = [];

function increment_row(index, amount) {
    if (rows[index]) {
        rows[index] += amount;
    } else {
        rows[index] = amount;
    }
}

// Count the cells in each row
$("tr").each(function (row_index, row_element) {
    var $row = $(row_element);
    $row.children().each(function (cell_index, cell_element) {
        var $cell = $(cell_element);
        var row_count = parseInt($cell.attr("rowspan"), 10) || 1;
        var col_count = parseInt($cell.attr("colspan"), 10) || 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < row_count; i++) {
             increment_row(row_index + i, col_count);        
        }
    })
});

// Find the row with the most cells
var sorted = rows.sort();
console.log(sorted[sorted.length - 1]);
```

Comment: thanks, your solution works, but looks a bit big, what you think about my solution? Why scan every row in a table if we can scan only thead?

Comment: @Martin — Because the number of columns in an HTML table is defined by the row with the most columns, not the first row.

Comment: using rowspan/colspan it's possible that none of the rows will have the maximum amount of columns. But the first row of any table always contains information about count of columns, through summing colspan and number of columns in it. If you're not agree, could you please provide an example of table which doesn't contain such information in its first row.

Comment: @Martin — "using rowspan/colspan it's possible that none of the rows will have the maximum amount of columns." — No, it isn't. It is possible that no TR element won't have a TD or TH element for each column, but that isn't the same thing.

Comment: @Martin — "But the first row of any table always contains information about count of columns" — Not true. `<table><tr><th>1<th>2<tr><td>1<td>2<td>3</table>`

Comment: By "contain information" I meant that the first row should contain either th/td or colspan for spanned th/td. In your example you must mention `colspan="2"` in the first or the second `th` of the first row, otherwise the table will appear broken. If I'm wrong please provide a working example.

Comment: "using rowspan/colspan it's possible that none of the rows will have the maximum amount of columns" should be written more clear: "using **rowspan** it's possible that none of the rows will have **the information about possible maximum number of columns**, except for the first one". By "possible maximum number of columns" I mean the row with th/td elements without any `colspan`. If it's not true, please provide a working example.

Comment: Here is the working example, in which you cannot get value `3` from any row except for the first one: https://jsfiddle.net/1ky92xsc/

Comment: "otherwise the table will appear broken" — That doesn't make it impossible, just ugly.

Comment: "Here is the working example, in which you cannot get value 3 from any row except for the first one" — That's because you are treating each row individually. My algorithm pays attention to rowspan attributes: https://jsfiddle.net/1ky92xsc/1/

Comment: OK, I see, you mean that the colspan doesn't required by the specification. I'll update my question and the choosen answer.

Comment: Only sample I found regarding both `colspan` and `rowspan` properties. Funny that people prefer *compact code* over *correct code*.

Answer (score -1):

To get total colspan count - Try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var colspan = 0;
  $( "th" ).each(function( index ) {
   if(typeof $(this).attr('colspan') != 'undefined') {
      colspan = colspan + parseInt($(this).attr('colspan'));
    }
    console.log(colspan)
  });
});
```

Comment: Could be written `$( "th" ).each(function( index ) 
   colspan += $(this).attr('colspan') || 0;`

Comment: It'll be $( "th" ).each(function( index ) { colspan += parseInt($(this).attr('colspan')) || 0; });

Comment: While this gives the correct answer for the particular set of data in the question, that is more by luck than judgement. It is just a coincidence that the sum of all the colspan attributes happens to be the same as the number of columns. If you add an extra `<th rowspan="3">Lorem</th>` then this code continues to claim that there are 11 columns when there are 12.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to make sure it was numeric

Answer (score -1):

Hunh, The deadliest way is either use [**`jQuery .filter`**](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) or [**`jQuery Attribute Selector`**](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

**`If you want this should be for all who has digits only use this:`**

```
$(function() {
  // Get total no of rowspan or colspan, if attr has numbers
  var NoOfColumnHasRowSpanOrColSpan = $('th').filter(function() {
    // check if attr exist
    var _rowspan = $(this).attr('rowspan');
    var _colspan = $(this).attr('colspan');
    // check if not undefined
    if (typeof _rowspan !== typeof undefined && _rowspan !== false) {
      // return if attr has value as number
      return /[0-9]/.test(_rowspan);
    }
    // same as above
    if (typeof _colspan !== typeof undefined && _colspan !== false) {
      return /[0-9]/.test(_colspan);
    }
  }).length;
  // get no of count th who has rowspan or colspan and digit as value
  alert(NoOfColumnHasRowSpanOrColSpan);
});
```

**`If you don't mind values:`**

```
$(function() {
  // Get total no of rowspan or colspan
  var NoOfColumnHasRowSpanOrColSpan = $('th[rowspan],th[colspan]').length;
  // get no of count th who has rowspan or colspan
  alert(NoOfColumnHasRowSpanOrColSpan);
});
```

[**Run DEMO:**](https://jsfiddle.net/neerajsinghsonu/20cd27ks/)

Comment: The number of cells which have a rowspan or colspan attribute is not the same as the number of columns in a table. The fact that it gives you the correct number for the table in the question is just a coincidence.

Comment: @Quentin: The question is about to count the column which has attributes rowspan or colspan. What is wrong in my code? Kindly explain..

Comment: No, the question was asking how many columns there are in the table. It just points out that when there are rowspan/colspan attributes you can't simply count the number of td/th elements.

Comment: @Quentin: No my code is not just counting all td or th, its works for only td or th who has 'colspan' or 'rowspan' attr and the user asked same question "How do I get the column count of a table when there are cells with rowspan/colspan?" that means he/she want to count the cell who has attr (col or row span).

Comment: No. It means that when a cell has a colspan, you have to count it as two (or however many) columns instead of one, and when a cell has a rowspan you have to count it as appearing multiple rows.

Comment: @Quentin: I am totally disagree with you, user aske "I need JavaScript/jQuery to get 11 for the following table:" and if you will see there is actually total 11 cells exist who has rowspan or colspan. It shows clearly that user wanna count all cell who has rowspan or colspan as attr. Kindly let me now if I am missing something...

Comment: If you count the number of columns then that also gives you 11. The fact that there are 11 cells which have colspan or rowspan attributes is just a coincidence. See also the answer that the OP actually accepted!

Comment: @Quentin: Ah!! now got it, user wanna count/sum the "value of all cell which has colspan attr. Whoosh! So sneaky man. Mind blowing :D Thanks :) I was just confused because of shit '11' :(